# unable to recieve sip call from external source on fusionpbx, error seems to be [WRONG_CALL_STATE] . how can i fix it

Tags: asterisk, pbx, freeswitch

Newbie here, I havejustall installed Fusionpbx in my debian based 1gb ram 40gb ssd server.I did also create several extensions but the calls from external sources are getting hanged up. I looked up the logs and error seems to be [CS_NEW] [WRONG_CALL_STATE]. How do i solve it. I have added latest error logs as well.

````
5abafa86-246b-405c-8f2a-d904ca623840 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1744 Session 9 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) Locked, Waiting on external entities
5abafa86-246b-405c-8f2a-d904ca623840 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1762 Session 9 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) Ended
5abafa86-246b-405c-8f2a-d904ca623840 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1766 Close Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 [CS_DESTROY]
5abafa86-246b-405c-8f2a-d904ca623840 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:735 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) Running State Change CS_DESTROY (Cur 5 Tot 14)
5abafa86-246b-405c-8f2a-d904ca623840 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) State DESTROY
5abafa86-246b-405c-8f2a-d904ca623840 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:380 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 SOFIA DESTROY
5abafa86-246b-405c-8f2a-d904ca623840 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:175 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 Standard DESTROY
5abafa86-246b-405c-8f2a-d904ca623840 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) State DESTROY going to sleep
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [WARNING] switch_core_state_machine.c:684 24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 Abandoned
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [NOTICE] switch_core_state_machine.c:687 Hangup sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 [CS_NEW] [WRONG_CALL_STATE]
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:581 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) Running State Change CS_HANGUP (Cur 5 Tot 14)
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:844 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) Callstate Change DOWN -> HANGUP
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:846 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) State HANGUP
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:469 Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 hanging up, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:59 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 Standard HANGUP, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:846 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) State HANGUP going to sleep
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:616 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) State Change CS_HANGUP -> CS_REPORTING
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:581 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) Running State Change CS_REPORTING (Cur 5 Tot 14)
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:932 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) State REPORTING
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:168 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 Standard REPORTING, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:932 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) State REPORTING going to sleep
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:607 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) State Change CS_REPORTING -> CS_DESTROY
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1744 Session 10 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) Locked, Waiting on external entities
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1762 Session 10 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) Ended
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1766 Close Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 [CS_DESTROY]
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:735 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) Running State Change CS_DESTROY (Cur 4 Tot 14)
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) State DESTROY
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:380 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 SOFIA DESTROY
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:175 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202 Standard DESTROY
24aab1e8-a3fc-48b6-ac10-d543f33fa7d8 2023-09-08 07:39:52.416393 98.90% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.202) State DESTROY going to sleep
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.636388 98.87% [WARNING] switch_core_state_machine.c:684 3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 Abandoned
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.636388 98.87% [NOTICE] switch_core_state_machine.c:687 Hangup sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 [CS_NEW] [WRONG_CALL_STATE]
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.636388 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:581 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Running State Change CS_HANGUP (Cur 4 Tot 14)
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.636388 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:844 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Callstate Change DOWN -> HANGUP
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.636388 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:846 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State HANGUP
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.636388 98.87% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:469 Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 hanging up, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:59 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 Standard HANGUP, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:846 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State HANGUP going to sleep
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:616 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State Change CS_HANGUP -> CS_REPORTING
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:581 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Running State Change CS_REPORTING (Cur 4 Tot 14)
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:932 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State REPORTING
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:168 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 Standard REPORTING, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:932 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State REPORTING going to sleep
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:607 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State Change CS_REPORTING -> CS_DESTROY
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1744 Session 11 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Locked, Waiting on external entities
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1762 Session 11 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Ended
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1766 Close Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 [CS_DESTROY]
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:735 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Running State Change CS_DESTROY (Cur 3 Tot 14)
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State DESTROY
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:380 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 SOFIA DESTROY
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:175 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 Standard DESTROY
3e924057-86e9-4871-bc4c-5f42d94896b9 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State DESTROY going to sleep
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [WARNING] switch_core_state_machine.c:684 bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 Abandoned
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [NOTICE] switch_core_state_machine.c:687 Hangup sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 [CS_NEW] [WRONG_CALL_STATE]
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:581 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Running State Change CS_HANGUP (Cur 3 Tot 14)
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:844 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Callstate Change DOWN -> HANGUP
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:846 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State HANGUP
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:469 Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 hanging up, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:59 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 Standard HANGUP, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:846 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State HANGUP going to sleep
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:616 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State Change CS_HANGUP -> CS_REPORTING
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:581 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Running State Change CS_REPORTING (Cur 3 Tot 14)
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:932 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State REPORTING
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:168 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 Standard REPORTING, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:932 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State REPORTING going to sleep
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:607 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State Change CS_REPORTING -> CS_DESTROY
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1744 Session 12 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Locked, Waiting on external entities
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1762 Session 12 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Ended
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1766 Close Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 [CS_DESTROY]
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:735 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) Running State Change CS_DESTROY (Cur 2 Tot 14)
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State DESTROY
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:380 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 SOFIA DESTROY
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:175 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203 Standard DESTROY
bb723d84-c4f2-4b01-987e-1b06e5a5548d 2023-09-08 07:39:54.656404 98.87% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.203) State DESTROY going to sleep
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [WARNING] switch_core_state_machine.c:684 c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 Abandoned
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [NOTICE] switch_core_state_machine.c:687 Hangup sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 [CS_NEW] [WRONG_CALL_STATE]
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:581 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Running State Change CS_HANGUP (Cur 2 Tot 14)
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:844 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Callstate Change DOWN -> HANGUP
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:846 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State HANGUP
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:469 Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 hanging up, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:59 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 Standard HANGUP, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:846 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State HANGUP going to sleep
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:616 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State Change CS_HANGUP -> CS_REPORTING
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:581 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Running State Change CS_REPORTING (Cur 2 Tot 14)
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:932 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State REPORTING
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:168 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 Standard REPORTING, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:932 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State REPORTING going to sleep
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:607 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State Change CS_REPORTING -> CS_DESTROY
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1744 Session 13 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Locked, Waiting on external entities
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1762 Session 13 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Ended
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1766 Close Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 [CS_DESTROY]
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:735 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Running State Change CS_DESTROY (Cur 1 Tot 14)
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State DESTROY
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:380 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 SOFIA DESTROY
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:175 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 Standard DESTROY
c5887afb-43e2-4d7f-b4fa-c81685fdfbd7 2023-09-08 07:39:56.876427 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State DESTROY going to sleep
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [WARNING] switch_core_state_machine.c:684 6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 Abandoned
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [NOTICE] switch_core_state_machine.c:687 Hangup sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 [CS_NEW] [WRONG_CALL_STATE]
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:581 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Running State Change CS_HANGUP (Cur 1 Tot 14)
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:844 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Callstate Change DOWN -> HANGUP
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:846 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State HANGUP
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:469 Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 hanging up, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:59 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 Standard HANGUP, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:846 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State HANGUP going to sleep
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:616 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State Change CS_HANGUP -> CS_REPORTING
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:581 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Running State Change CS_REPORTING (Cur 1 Tot 14)
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:932 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State REPORTING
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:168 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 Standard REPORTING, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:932 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State REPORTING going to sleep
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:607 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State Change CS_REPORTING -> CS_DESTROY
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1744 Session 14 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Locked, Waiting on external entities
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1762 Session 14 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Ended
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1766 Close Channel sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 [CS_DESTROY]
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:735 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) Running State Change CS_DESTROY (Cur 0 Tot 14)
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State DESTROY
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:380 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 SOFIA DESTROY
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:175 sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211 Standard DESTROY
6c84f936-e01b-4e8e-baf7-718730d900bc 2023-09-08 07:39:56.916450 98.83% [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:745 (sofia/internal/+12519104302@52.144.2.211) State DESTROY going to sleep```
````

Comment: ask the provider for support at first and then take a long read on [ask] ;)